# Contact form with AngularJs not working

Tags: angularjs

I have found a tutorial on how to work with the angular js, but when I try to implement it into my work, I do not get the same results.
Here is the original:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keren7/TcvxX/)

And here is my work:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keren7/YZgam/5/)

My code for some reason does not show the error labels/ messages and if it does, it shows it under the input field instead of besides it.

```
 <div class="input-prepend">    
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>

      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full name (Required)" data-ng-model="name" name="name" type="text" ng-minlength="3"> 
      <span class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && helpForm.name.$error.required">Required!</span>
      <span class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && helpForm.name.$error.minlength">Name too short!</span>

 </div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: kindly avoid this "input-prepend" naming convention and try with convention like "inputPrepend"...

but i don't think so "input-prepend" is name of your for..
the hierarchy should like formName.elementName.$error.required same for minlegth

Comment: Sorry, I was just playing around and forgot to remove it. Thanks for noticing, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

The css class "input-prepend" defines a font-size of 0 (zero!) pixel. Your error labels are children of a div with this class and have a font-size of 75%. This gives a font-size of 0*0.75=0 pixel. Pretty hard to read...

Comment: How did you fix it, and what exactly isn't working? Maybe you could provide a new fiddle? I tried your jsFiddle - removing the font-size style from the input-prepend class (via Web Developer tool in the browser) was sufficient to make the labels appear.

Comment: The phone validation is not working and I can't seem to figure out how to make choosing the category as required.
http://plnkr.co/edit/5LQauDjOL5ug8rQBCDUk?p=preview

Comment: phone validation: see http://plnkr.co/edit/sO1TThxlfbw3uLFSuoe6?p=preview You need to set the pattern on the scope inside the controller, not in a script tag in index.html. Making the category required: didn't look into it yet (it's past midnight local time), hopefully tomorrow

Comment: @user3093322 Sorry, couldn't find time earlier. As for the categories: "required" is an attribute for input elements, not divs. One trick that worked for me was inserting a hidden input into the button group div and connect it to the selected category: `<input type="hidden" name="toggle" ng-model="toggle" required>`